# In Java 11, how do you get a sonarLint warning-free way of getting an index?

Tags: java, string, random, java-11, sonarlint

I'm using Java 11 and SonarLint.  I have this code for getting a random index in a string (SALTCHARS is a string of length 36)

```
  int index = (int) (rnd.nextFloat() * SALTCHARS.length());
```

However, using SonarLint, this generates this warning

[image]

I can't simply replace "nextFloat" with "nextInt" as that functionally changes the result of this code.  What is a SonarLint-safe way of generating a random index in a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int index = rnd.nextInt(SALTCHARS.length());
```